# Могут ли поля разных таблиц иметь одинаковые названия в MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте. Вопрос сформулирован в заголовке.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Могут, разумеется. Вы никогда не видели таблицы, в каждой из которых было бы поле id, например?

Comment: просто в запросе писать какое поле интерисует конкретно типа "таблица.поле"?

Comment: @MuscledBoy Да, таблица.поле или алиас.поле ну типа `select A.name from very_long_table_name A where ...`

Comment: Да. Если речь про выборки, то можно задать полю псевдоним, чтобы было проще работать с результатом:`select foo.id as foo_id, bar.id as bar_id from foo, bar`